# Import virtual disk to GCP Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a VMDK disk image of a ubuntu machine which was exported out of GCP sometime ago. Now I want to import this image into GCP and use it as a base image for new compute machine. I think the only way to import externally store virtual disk is to route it via Storage/Bucket. When I upload the required image file on the bucket folder, it takes many many hours to import the image of size 4gb. Is it normal for the import process to take this long? are there any other short cuts to this? The import process failed midway and I had to restart couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the relevant [gcloud compute images import command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/import), which supports both using Cloud Storage or a local file within the environment where you are running the gcloud command.

Notice that the tool uses Cloud Build under the hood, requires certain permissions and has some limitations. For a more detailed information of the correct procedure to be followed please refer to the relevant section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks).

Comment: I tried to use gcloud command you described. Unfortunately I did not know how to reference local file from console. I simpley used the UI to import the file into storage and created an image out of it. thanks anyway.